# Gravar tópico numérico (1 1.2, 1.2.1) no MySQL com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou com seguinte problema: Preciso gravar em um banco de dados algumas condicionantes, que tem seus números de item e subitem como nesse exemplo:

1. Teste 1
2. Teste 2

   2.1 Teste

Tentei fazer com `numeric(4,2)` ou `float` porém quando acontece de uma condicionante ter mais subitens, por exemplo 2.2.1, já não funciona mais. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Nenhuma dessas abordagens é a correta. Vamos supor que você esteja colocando os registros assim:

```
numero | nome
1      | Teste 1
2      | Teste 2
2.1    | Teste
2.1.1  | Outro teste
```

A solução seria criar duas novas coluna, uma para ser a nova chave primária e uma com o id do registro pai:

```
id | id_pai | numero | nome
1  | null   |      1 | Teste 1
2  | null   |      2 | Teste 2
3  | 2      |      1 | Teste
4  | 3      |      1 | Outro teste
```

Obviamente, o campo `id_pai` seria uma chave estrangeira para o campo `id` da mesma tabela. O campo `id` seria a chave primária. O número é formado percorrendo-se o registro pai, avô, etc até chegar em um `null` e ir concatenando os valores do campo `numero` que forem encontrados.

Comment: E para ordernação das condicionantes? Eu posso colocar mais de um campo na condional MYSQL, tipo ORDER BY (id,numero) ou são varias SQL em um laço de repetição?